# Function to compare words to solve word game in Python

Tags: python, function, anagram

Im trying to find/write a function to compare two words in a Python program that solves a word puzzle game.
The goal of the game is to create as many word as possible using a set of 9 letters, the words can be between 4 and 9 letters long (the words are anagrams of the original 9 letters but do not have to be 9 letters long).
The set of 9 letters are read in as a string from the user.
Basically the function needs to check the words in a word list (txt file which is converted to list of strings) if they are anagrams of the user inputs, and if so print word to the screen.

I have tried the python all() function but does not work since it does not take into account the frequency of characters in the user input (example: if user input contains only two A's, word should not be printed if it contains more than two A's).

Comment: "collections.Counter" can help here, especially if you use Python 3.10 or later (rich comparison).

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
# Prints all the anagrams
def check(letters, word):
    if(sorted(letters) <= sorted(word)):
        print(word)
# NOTE: 'letters' is the user input. As this function is going to be called a lot of times, user input should be sorted outside this function.
```

```
# Cabs: True
check('aabbcccss', 'cabs')
# Array: False (two A's needed and two R's needed)
check('aryqwetyu', 'array')
```

If you want to know the letters of every word that are not included in the user input, you could use Counter instead: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.subtract

```
from collections import Counter

# Prints the letters included in the word, but not included in the user's input
def check(letters, word):
    print(f'{letters} - {word}')
    c = Counter(letters)
    w = Counter(word)
    c.subtract(w)
    for k,v in dict(c).items():
        if v < 0:
            print(f'{-v} {k}\'s missing.')
    print('--------')
```

```
# cabs - aabbcccss
# --------
check('aabbcccss', 'cabs')
# array - aryqwetyu
# 1 a's missing.
# 1 r's missing.
# --------
check('aryqwetyu', 'array')
```